# Is Esri GeoPortal compatible with ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoportal, esri-geoportal-server

I am attempting to set up GeoPortal 1.2.4 and use ArcGIS 10.2 as my client desktop.  I haven't come across any documentation which says these are compatible other than the Git page.  However, I am unable to set up my software, I am getting a message which says 10.1 is not installed.

https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Preinstallation-1.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as the GIT page is the only source of information regarding system requirements ([ArcGIS Desktop section](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Preinstallation-1.2.4#wiki-arcgis-desktop)) because at the [Esri page](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal/system-requirements), they refer to the github link.

> ArcGIS Desktop 10, 10.1 or 10.2 is required for using the Geoportal
>   Clients for ArcGIS Desktop. The Geoportal Clients are offered in
>   versions specific to your ArcGIS environment; i.e., use the 10.1
>   Geoportal Clients with ArcGIS 10.1, and the 10 Geoportal Clients with
>   ArcGIS 10. The Geoportal Clients allow users to connect to the
>   geoportal from within ArcGIS Desktop to publish and search. Caution:
>   The ArcGIS Desktop .NET Framework option must be enabled during
>   installation of ArcGIS Desktop on any machine that will be using the
>   Geoportal Clients.

There is a good-looking Esri installation guide published as a white paper:
[How to Set Up Esri® Geoportal Server 1.2.2 on Windows: Aggregate Geospatial Resources with Open Source Technology](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/how-to-set-up-geoportal-server-122.pdf).

Esri has published [two desktop clients](https://github.com/Esri/geoportal-server/wiki/Geoportal-Server-Downloads) 1.2.4 - one for 10.1 and another for 10.2, so this implies that geoportal is supported with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 indeed.

Comment: Glad it played out well.